# Culture specific order of date elements

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to display the month with letters and the day for the users. I could use `DateTime.ToString("MMMM d");` but in some countries the correct format would be `d MMMMM`.

Is there a way to to ensure the order is always right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a way. Just a quick browse through

```
[Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures) | 
    select @{l='Culture';e={$_.Name}},@{l='Pattern';e={$_.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern}}
```

reveals a lot of cultures where there are things around the month name and the day that need to be included in some and excluded in some others.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to to ensure the order is always right?

Well, the closest I can think of would be to get the right "long date format" (e.g. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern` and then remove any element you didn't want.

However, this will be quite a brittle approach, and I'd recommend that you test *thoroughly* with all the cultures you particularly care about. For example, you'll need to think about any culture where the long date pattern doesn't include "MMMM"... or take `en-US` for example, where the long date pattern uses `dd` instead of `d`. What would you want to do in those situations?

Then there's the whole genitive vs non-genitive forms - I *suspect* that for any cultures where it matters, both the long date format and the "month day" format you're after would use the same form... but it all gets pretty messy, to be honest.

Comment: That's why I started looking at every `LongDatePattern` ;-). I couldn't think of any transformation that would work reliably :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `ToString()` overload that takes a `CultureInfo` and use the appropriate culture.

For example:

```
var american = new CultureInfo("en-us");
var dateString = new DateTime(2000,1,1).ToString("MMMM d", american);
```

yields "January 1".

More info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487532/tostring0-versus-tostringcultureinfo-invariantculture).

Comment: The invariant culture is never the right thing to display to a user.

Comment: True, but I don't know what culture is the right culture in this context. InvariantCulture should be replaced with the right one for his purposes.

Comment: @neontapir: At which point you've not answered the question at all - please re-read it.

Comment: I disagree. If he wants to display the date consistently in a certain format, he can use a specific culture that uses that format. I've amended my example.

Comment: It's not about using a single consistent format. It's about using a format that is consistent with the culture the user uses, regardless of which one that is.

Comment: If that's the case, Joey, then I misread the intent of the question and withdraw my answer. I had a requirement similar to the one I described, where the system stored dates in US English, and it caused date parsing problems when it was run on a UK English server.

Comment: @neontapir: A system *storing* dates using things like month names would *never* be a good idea. If you have to transmit date information in text at all, you'd definitely want to use something which didn't rely on culture-specific names.

Comment: Agreed, in this case it was short date format. Point well taken. [This site](http://www.burch-swm.com/a3.html) talks about a similar issue to the one I'm describing.